# Обработка событий в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

У меня в представлении(Form.cshtml) есть кнопка:
`<a href="~/Home/Form" type="button">Ввести данные</a>`

Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на неё на странице появились вот эти элементы:

```
     <p>Выберите тип поиска фильма:</p>
        <ul>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox"> Название</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox"> Актёры</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox"> Жанр</label></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: почему бы их сразу не сделать в этой view скрытыми и показывать, когда требуется?

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: <p style="display: none">...  тут почитать: https://htmlacademy.ru/courses/44/run/22  А с помощью javascript - кода можно менять класс нужного блока, чтобы его отображать/скрывать на странице. Если есть jquery.js , то можно скрыть элеиент <p id="myblock">...</ p>  $("#myblock").hide()  / .show() или используя .toggle()

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
<a href="~/Home/Form" type="button" id= "button">Ввести данные</a>
<span id="content" style="display:none">
      <p>Выберите тип поиска фильма:</p>
        <ul>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox"> Название</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox"> Актёры</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox"> Жанр</label></li>
        </ul>
</span>

<script>
$("#button").click(function(){ $("#content").css("display","block");})
</script>
```